# UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW - Insert

Tags: locking

I am inserting records into a custom object via interface.

I deactivated the triggers on this object so there is no additional code getting triggered upon insert.

Still i am receiving the error:

> UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW:unable to obtain exclusive access to this record

I understand if this error comes during update but upon insert also this error is thrown... which is strange to me.

**Any suggestions on how to solve this?**

Comment: There's not enough information here. **You need to contact support.** The error might be related to a number of things, such as workflow rules, rollup summary fields, using the "avoid skipping auto-number* features, and so on. Triggers are not the only cause of this error, and a detailed analysis from support will be more beneficial to you short-term than asking a question that's overly broad hoping someone will happen to guess which reason applies to your specific situation.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. There are no workflow rules, role up summary fields. there is an autonumber & few formula fields. When you say contact support, do you mean salesforce support? I am a developer myself but the error is not descriptive enough to understand what might be causing it. Also whereever i read about this error in salesforce articles, it says two processes trying to update the same record causes this issues and there are no additional details like  workflow rules, rollup summary fields, using the "avoid skipping auto-number* features. Do you have any link to which gives this info?

Comment: I recommend contacting support, because it's going to be very tough tracking this down. I've been in salesforce for nearly eleven years now, and I still can't tell you all the possible causes. Your best bet is to turn on debugging (Setup > Monitoring > Debug Logs), and hope you can catch the error in a log. It might provide more details. Other than that, definitely contact technical support. They have more resources available than us outsiders.

Comment: Can you please check and let us all know the different lookups you may be populating for this object's record.